# Cannot access member functions of vector<int>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I've been attempting to figure out this bug for about an hour now. It's probably a really obvious syntax thing I'm overlooking. This is my first C++ project, and I don't have a good handle on the structure of the language.

Here's my header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class BoardState
{

private:
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int SIZE;

public:
    BoardState();

    std::vector<int> getState();

    bool isZero();
};
```

And here's the implementation, in a separate file:

```
#include "BoardState.h"

BoardState::BoardState(){
    SIZE = 4;
    numbers.push_back(1);
    numbers.push_back(3);
    numbers.push_back(5);
    numbers.push_back(7);
}

std::vector<int> BoardState::getState() { return numbers; }

bool BoardState::isZero() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        if (numbers[i] != 0) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code is *really simple*, so I have no clue what could be going wrong to produce the errors. However, on every method call, *push_back* and *size*, I am getting errors, saying that *class "std::vector<int, allocator>" has no member "method_name_here"*.

My background is Java, so my first thought was that I wasn't able to call these methods because *numbers* is not initialized. However, any attempt I made to initialize *numbers* in the header file resulted in an error as well. I tried `std::vector<int> numbers = { 1,3,5,7 };`, I tried `std::vector<int> numbers(4,0);`, I even tried creating an array and constructing the vector from that. Not only did all those attempts cause errors, they also didn't fix the method calls either.

What am I missing? Do I need to initialize the vector, or is what I have in the header file enough? Any advice would be helpful here, since I can't find anything online about similar errors. I've even copy-pasted code from StackOverflow answers about similar problems, and that produced errors as well.

**EDIT**: I've pared down the code as much as possible while keeping the error:

```
#include <vector>

class BoardState
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    BoardState() { numbers.push_back(1); }
    int getSize() { 
        int i = numbers.size(); 
        return i;
    }
};
```

On the line `numbers.push_back(1);`, my compiler underlines the token "push_back", and highlighting it reads:

*class "std::vector<int, allocator>" has no member "push_back"*

On the line `int i = numbers.size();`, the token "size" is underlined, and the error reads:

*class "std::vector<int, allocator>" has no member "size"*

I still have no clue what's going on.

**Edit 2**: Put the method calls into a constructor and a function. This changed the error message associated with push_back().

**Edit 3**: I have discovered something very disconcerting. This code works perfectly fine in a different compiler. I copy-pasted in the exact code from Edit 1 and it ran with no issues. I think the problem must be with Visual Studio rather than the actual code. Thank you all for helping me out with this. I think I'm just going to switch to a different compiler and hope for the best.

**Edit 4**: Just to prove to pm100 that my code is exactly as I've said, here's a screenshot from visual studio.
[Here it is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYk7K.png)

Aside from the main method, this is character-for-character what I've put in this question. I have a guess as to why this doesn't work, though. I modified my version of Visual Studio 2019 to run .386 assembly code for a college class. While I think I followed the guide to do that without affecting anything else, it may have screwed up parts of the C++ compiler.

Comment: can you post the full error message for the code in question?

Comment: I canʼt reproduce the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/1nPebq

What system are you using, and as Shaggi asked, can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Reproduce, I cannot. [mre] you must provide.

Comment: What is the very first error?

Comment: to add what other have said, your code should work, so please post the exact error message and the exact code

Comment: your simplified code works too, you are not doing what you are actually showing, you are showing what you think you are doing

Comment: Re: `You can't have code like numbers.push_back(1); inside a class. It needs to be in a function.` Why? @cigien

Comment: what platform? c++ compiler etc

Comment: I was referring to a previous edit. That's not allowed, but your code is changed now.

Comment: Visual Studio might have some problems, but certainly NOT with this code. What version are you on?

Comment: this is not a bug in visual studio. no vendor could ever ship a compiler that fails what you typed. You did not type what you think you typed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could select `Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset all settings-> Visual C++` to restore the default settings.

If it does not work, you could reinstall VS.